# Pure JS video editing

Tags: javascript, video

Is it possible to cut and splice video clips in javascript? I've seen little hints around the web that folks might be doing this. Anyone doing this, or aware of anyone else doing it? I can imagine some ways to simulate this using canvas or css, but I'm hoping there is a way to just chop a video file into pieces or concatenate two video files directly.

Comment: I know some video-editing suites incorporate scripting api's. you could try looking around for one that supports javascript

Comment: I was just looking to see if youtube's editor had an api but it doesn't seem like it. I'll keep looking.